# Switching from MockBackend to Actual API in Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angular, typescript

I am working on login functionality for my Angular 2 app. I've got it working with a MockMackend and fakeBackendProvider. Now I'm in the process of connecting to our actual API. I am running into an issue with that, though.

First off, let me show what I have that IS working by using the MockBackend and fakeBackendProvider.

This is my authentication service function:

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post('/api/authenticate', JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password}))
        .map((response: Response) => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            const user = response.json();
            if (user && user.token) {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
            }
        });
}
```

Again, then, in my login component, I am calling that function like this:

```
login() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.router.navigate(['/']);
                console.log('User logged in as: ' + this.model.username);
            },
            error => {
                this.alertService.error(error);
                this.loading = false;
            });
            this.authenticationService.username = this.model.username;
}
```

Again, all of the above *IS* working.

So, I assume all I should need to do is replace '/api/authenticate' in the login function, with our actual api + api string. So this is what I've been trying:

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post('https://api.somesite.com&apikey=843c-4932-ckd33', JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password}))
        .map((response: Response) => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            const user = response.json();
            if (user && user.token) {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
            }
        });
}
```

This isn't working. In the console I get a "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" error. Any ideas here?

Comment: check for typos in the url and make sure it works when you paste it in the browser

Comment: Thanks, I did try that. And in the browser it doesn't work either. Does that mean the constructed url call is wrong? What should I see in the browser?

Comment: You are doing a ```post``` in your app, in the browser it will be a ```get```. It wouldn't login in the browser using a get, but it should return some kind of response.

Comment: Right. That's helpful, thanks. So I will check into the actual post I am sending.

Comment: You are missing your headers as well...

Comment: That hasn't been necessary in other api calls I'm doing. Guessing it's not necessary here either. For instance, this kind of call works as is:
https://api.somesite.com/v0/clients/325ab67d4c9ad4dw1ce?apikey=1h3h5h41d-4j5j-56j3

Comment: @Muirik is that an get or post request? Get request shouldn't need headers. But yeah, figure out the url is correct first :)

Comment: @AJT_82 - Actually, you're correct in this instance. Because we're sending usernames and passwords here, post is the safer way to go, so I do need to adjust accordingly.

Comment: `https://api.somesite.com&apikey=843c-4932-ckd33` is not a valid URL.